# Line height unexpectedly causes height to be higher

Tags: css

In this fiddle, if you inspect the nav element, you will see that the computed height of the nav element is 61px. I expect it to be 60px. Why is it 61?

https://jsfiddle.net/p2kgpfqr/

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <a>bkaksfd</a>
    <a>kkwaekfwae</a>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: It's showing up as 60px for me using chrome

Comment: You should add in which browser (and OS) you are seeing this. Chrome is showing 60px for me, but Firefox is showing 61px (on Win 10).

Comment: on Firefox Mac it's 60px

Answer (score 0):

The height in nav is 60px

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onBNV.png)

Comment: The height in nav what exactly, can you explain ?

Comment: with chrome F12 inspect element, you can see the width and height of the nav, is 60px, please see the img attach

Answer (score 0):

line-height is related to typography and it defines minimum height of the element. It does not ensure the exact height of the element. Rendering different fonts will change the height too. In your case, for example, you if you use serif font family height becomes 61, while using sans-serif family height becomes 60. You need to use height property to ensure the exact height.

Comment: Based on the comments, you can see that rendering differs even between  browsers and os.

Comment: This would mean line-height is a poor way to do vertical alignment of single line text

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` defines the amount of space from the top of one line to the top of the next. The top of the first line of text, however, does not align with the top of the parent element due to the default `vertical-align: baseline`. The extra space results in a difference in computed heights.

This can be resolved by setting `vertical-align` to `top` or `bottom`.